# How to literally translate this: 已经在有意识地把这种情感影响，甚至把人性的价值判断？

Tags: translation

你看这个老师在讲童话的时候，已经在有意识地把这种情感影响，甚至把人性的价值判断，都给了孩子们。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 22. I would like to have your help in its literal translation. I have got to that point:

你(you)看(see)这(this)个(classifier)老师(teacher)在(in)讲(telling)童话(fairy tale)的时候(time)，已经(already)在(in)有(having)意识地(consciously)把(把)这(this)种(kind of)情感(emotional or emotion)影响(impact or influence)，甚至(even)把(把)人性(human nature)的价值(value or worth)判断(judgement)，都给了(gave to)孩子们(children)。

I have the following specific questions:

1. The first 在 together with the 时候 means when? 在讲童话的时候 = 在[讲童话的]时候 = in [讲童话的] time = when [讲童话的] = when (the teacher) was telling fairy tales. Am I right or do I miss something?
2. How to make the following part make sense? 已经(already)在(in)有(having)意识地(consciously)把(把)这(this)种(kind of)情感(emotional or emotion)影响(impact or influence)?
3. In the following part, the grammar noun noun noun structure: 人性(human nature)的价值(value or worth)判断(judgement) really perplexes me. Do I miss some ofs or some of these words are adjectives?

Answer (score 2):

> How to literally translate

Don't do that, all you get is gibberish!

Without more context I would translate your sentence this way:

在 ... 的时候：when
有意识：consciously
情感影响：emotional influence
人性的价值判断： value judgements on human nature

你看这个老师在讲童话的时候，
When you watch this teacher telling fairy tales,
已经在有意识 地把这种情感影响，
(he/she) is already consciously imparting to the children(给了孩子们) a kind of emotional influence,
甚至把人性的价值判断，
(and) even value judgements on human nature.
都给了孩子们。

Maybe simplify like this:

她已经在有意识地把这种情感影响给了孩子们。
She is already consciously imparting to the children this/a kind of emotional influence.

她已经在有意识地把人性的价值判断给了孩子们。
She is already imparting to the children value judgements on human nature.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I don't quite like the sentence. The translation below is my best shot with some opinionated modifications. And, as usual, it is not a word-to-word translation but stays close to the original content.

"你看这个老师在讲童话的时候，已经在有意识地把这种情感影响，甚至把人性的价值判断，都给了孩子们。"

"You see that during the fairy storytelling, the teacher has already consciously taken hold of and imparted this kind of emotional influence/impact, altogether with the human value and judgment, to the kids."

Note 1 - the English equivalent of "在...期间/时候" is "during". In the phrase "已经(在)有意识地...", "在" is unnecessary and can/should be omitted.

Note 2 - 把 = take hold of.